# Docker TypeScript: No hot loading when I make changes to the files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, nodemon

Basically when I make changes to my ts files, it is not reflected in the browser nor the console which should show the refreshed logs. I am using nodemon to handles the typescript changes and all using Docker and docker-compose. The docker-compose is outside the server folder and the main files of the server folder are stored in an src subfolder

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "watch": [
    "src",
    ".env"
  ],
  
  "ext": "js,ts,json",
  "ignore": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --nolazy -r ts-node/register"
  }
}
```

**packaje.json scripts**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./build node build/app.js",
    "inspect": "nodemon --inspect src/app.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

**Docker**

```
FROM node:16
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . . 

RUN yarn install
```

**docker-compose for the server only**

```
server:
        container_name: server
        build: 
            context: ./server
        command: yarn run dev 
        volumes: 
            - ./server/src:/usr/app/src
            - ./server/nodemon.json:/usr/app/src/nodemon.json
```

Comment: Can you run `yarn run dev` on the host, without Docker involved?  What benefit do you get from introducing Docker into this setup?

Comment: yarn run dev on the host hot reloads it. I am using docker because i would be use using mongodb database and hosting on digital ocean.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things you could try doing here!

**1. Nodemon Config**

For context, this suggestion results after reviewing [this tutorial](https://dev.to/dariansampare/setting-up-docker-typescript-node-hot-reloading-code-changes-in-a-running-container-2b2f) which looked similar to what you were building!

Double check that the Nodemon config file is formatted and named properly. In the post it looks like you named it `nodemon.js` while it's being mounted in the Docker container as `nodemon.json`.

As well, possibly expand the `src` directive in the Nodemon configuration to `src/**/*.ts`. I'm unsure which files you're changing to trigger the hot reload, but this will tell Nodemon to search all subdirectories of the `src` folder for Typescript file changes specifically.

**2. Alternative Solution Using Transpiled Typescript**

In the past, I've used built Javascript to surface hot reloading for Typescript in a Docker container. This was on a server, with a similar directory structure to what you described. It might be a viable last resort.

Here are some steps:

1. Install `concurrently` (a package to run multiple commands at the same time)

```
yarn add -D concurrently
```

2. Update your scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "tsc -w",    // Typescript watcher, will retranspile TS to JS in the dist folder when changes are made
  "dev": "nodemon -L dist/index.js", // Runs nodemon in legacy mode, 'dist/index.js' is the file the Typescript is transpiled to
  "start": "concurrently -k \"npm:watch\" \"npm:dev\"" // Runs the Typescript watcher and nodemon at the same time
}
```

3. Update your compose mounts (nodemon config mount can be added, although it would be optional)

```
 command:
   yarn start  
 volumes:
   ./server/src:/usr/app/src
```

Once again, totally could be a last resort. However, by doing this, the Typescript watcher will retranspile your code whenever you make changes and nodemon will receive those changes in `dist`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the nodemon to work with the inside the container. First i installed the nodemon globally

```
FROM node:16
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn global add nodemon
RUN yarn install
```

then the command in docker-compose

```
command: nodemon /usr/app/src/index.js
```